# Maximal parahoric subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove Proposition 2.7.3 from I.G. Macdonald's book "Spherical Functions on a Group of $p$-adic Type":

> > **Proposition 2.7.3:** Every compact subgroup of $G$ is contained in a maximal compact subgroup. The maximal compact subgroups are precisely the maximal parahoric subgroups, and form $(l+1)$ conjugacy classes. All parahoric subgroups are open and compact. $G$ itself is locally compact, but not compact.

For context, here $G$ is a simply connected group of $p$-adic type (and specifically with a specific $BN$-pair and subgroups $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in \Sigma}$ defined earlier in the book, $N$ and $U_\alpha$ are closed subgroups of $G$ and $B$ is an open compact subgroup of $G$).

The second half of this seems quite straightforward (and it mentions it in the book), where the parahoric subgroups are finite unions of cosets $BwB$ so they are compact, while $G$ is not a finite union of the $BwB$ so it isn't compact.
But I can't quite wrap my head around the first part.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't this just be a standard Zorn's lemma argument?

Comment: Yes, that should be the first part. But how do I show that there are $l+1$ conjugacy classes?

Comment: What is $l$? You don't define this in your post.

Answer (score 2):

A geometric approach, avoiding BN pairs, is more informative and intuitive:

There exists a certain $l$-dimensional simplicial complex (a Bruhat-Tits building) $X$ on which $G$ acts via automorphisms, transitively on chambers (maximal simplices). Fixing one such chamber (a **fundamental chamber**) one defines maximal standard parahoric subgroups of $G$ as stabilizers of the vertices of this chamber: Since the chamber has dimension $l$, it has $l+1$ vertices. These vertices have disjoint orbits, hence, there are $l+1$ conjugacy classes of parahoric subgroups of $G$, represented by the standard parahorics.

Compactness of parahorics is a consequence of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

The complex $X$ has **nonpositive curvature**, which implies the existence and uniqueness of a center of mass of any bounded subset. In particular, since orbits of compact subgroups $H< G$ are bounded, the center of such an orbit is a point $x$ fixed by $H$. Since the action is simplicial, $H$ will fix pointwise the smallest face of $X$ containing $x$. By conjugating $H$ in $H$, this face is a face of the fundamental chamber. Hence, $H$ fixes one of the vertices of the fundamental chamber, hence, is a subgroup of one of the standard parahoric subgroups.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old answer. I wonder, where in your answer is simply connectedness of $G$ used ?

Comment: @Suzet: That's not needed (for instance, $PSL(2,Q_p)$ is not simply connected). What you really need is a BN pair. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Building_(mathematics)) and the references given there.

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply! What I find confusing may be the following. It looks like you proved that any compact subgroup $H$ of $G$ lies inside a maximal parahoric subgroup. In particular, maximal compact subgroups should be maximal parahoric subgroups. However, the answer by Paul Broussous in the following MO post says that it requires $G$ to be simply connected as an algebraic group (over an algebraic closure): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242645/when-are-maximal-compacts-same-as-maximal-parahorics . But, maybe I am missing something..